# How to minimize the number of webservice calls using Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, debouncing

In my Android Kotlin project, I call a webservice in a coroutine (`myWebservice` is just a custom class that manages webservice calls):

```kotlin
fun searchForItems(userInput: String)
{
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()).launch {
        val listOfItems = myWebService.call(userInput)
    }
}
```

That method is called everytime a user types a character in an `EditText`, so the app calls a webservice that returns a list of items matching his request. But I want to optimize that.

Let's say that the user types the word: "apple". In order to minimise the number of webservice calls, here is what I want to achieve:

- when the user types the first letter (a), the webservice is called
- when the user types the next letters, there is no new webservice call as long as the first called hasn't returned (let's assume that he has enough time to type the next letters (pple))
- when the first webservice call is done, a new call is done automatically with the new user input (apple)

What would be the best practices to achieve that?
Or is there a better way to minimize the number of webservice calls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Using Kotlin coroutines I solved it like this:

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var searchJob: Job? = null

    fun search(userInput: String) {
        searchJob?.cancel() // cancel previous job when user enters new letter
        searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(300)      // add some delay before search, this function checks if coroutine is canceled, if it is canceled it won't continue execution
            val listOfItems = myWebService.call(userInput)
            ...
        }
    }  
}
```

When user enters first letter `search()` function is called, coroutine is launched and `Job` of this coroutine is saved to `searchJob`. Then `delay(300)` function is called to wait for another user input before calling the WebService. If user enters another letter before 300 milliseconds expire `search()` function will be called again and previous coroutine will be cancelled using `searchJob?.cancel()` function and WebService will not be called in the first coroutine.

Answer (score 2):

To optimize web service calls you can use `StateFlow` and its `debounce` operator. For example in `ViewModel`:

```
val inputFlow = MutableStateFlow("")

init {
    inputFlow
        .debounce(300) // filters out values that are followed by the newer values within the given timeout. The latest value is always emitted.
        .filterNot { userInput -> userInput.isEmpty() } //  filter the unwanted string like an empty string in this case to avoid the unnecessary network call.
        .distinctUntilChanged() // to avoid duplicate network calls
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // Changes the context where this flow is executed to Dispatchers.IO
        .onEach { userInput -> // go through each filtered userInput
            val listOfItems = myWebService.call(userInput)
            // do sth with listOfItems
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}

fun searchForItems(userInput: String) {
    inputFlow.value = userInput
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **debouncing**. Coroutines or not, you shouldn't call the web service with each letter for every active user. That will eventually DDOS the web service if your app is used by many people at once.

Since you are using Kotlin, instead of coroutines you can use Flow. It comes with a built in [`debounce`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html) method. Also the stream of letters is easily modelled as a flow. It would be something like this (I'm not sure this even runs, but you get the idea):

```
textFlow = flow {
    myTextView.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> emit(text)}
}.debounce(1000)
```

The more complex alternative is RxJava's [`debounce` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html).

You can also try LiveData with [lupajz's debounce extension](https://gist.github.com/lupajz/43068881d949e207d5efe2c40bde1866)

Or you can also roll your own solution.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, I was thinking of Flow. That said, I don't understand how to bind it to a user input event. Could you provide an example, or a link, by any chance?

Comment: Added snippet for Flow

Comment: Well, I'll have to go for a custom solution, but I learned something new, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality using Rx Java's debounce operator. every time you will enter a text in Edit Text Rx Java's debounce will call the webservice and quickly will produce result and if Again user enter another text it will then call the web service.

Please refer the below link for batter understaing , So you can modify your code and achieve same functinolaity

https://blog.mindorks.com/implement-search-using-rxjava-operators-c8882b64fe1d

```
RxSearchObservable.fromView(searchView)
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(String text) {
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        })
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(String query) {
                return dataFromNetwork(query)
                        .doOnError(throwable -> {
                            // handle error
                        })
                        // continue emission in case of error also
                        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> "");
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String result) {
                textViewResult.setText(result);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApiUpdateTask: Deferred<Unit>? = null
  
fun getApiResponse() = viewModelScope.launch {
    myApiUpdateTask?.cancel()
    myApiUpdateTask = async {
        delay(500)
        // TODO: your api request 
    }
}
```

Using this structure inside the viewmodel; You can wait for 500 milliseconds and send the request you will send consecutively.